# binding one input element value to another element value

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on some sort of poll creation site

i have questions and each question has it's options

this options can be either static as radio buttons or dynamic as radio buttons with text box

and by dynamic i mean the visitor can enter his value for this option eg:

question 1:

option 1 radio
option 2 radio
option 3 radio textbox

i need to bind the  radio button value to the dedicated text box value how ?

Comment: can you add some punctuation? Not being an ass, honestly can't understand your question.

Comment: I concur, I have no idea what the question is about, i get lost on line 2

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'bind' the values of both inputs as they are different ones. The first is a `type="radio"` and the second is `type="text"` if I understood your question correctly.

Why does that matter to you though? You can use a naming convention that will allow you to analyze which text input belongs to which question number/radio button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the third option is like "other" option for the visitor if i have three options for this question like 1 2 3 the "other" option let the user enter his choice like 5 6 apple etc i want to make this text value to be sent instead the radio button value in this option

Comment: You can name both radio buttons and text input per question the same, and then write a javascript code that will disable the radio button input if the user filled in something in the input box of that question. That should work nicely.

Comment: all the radio boxes have the same name to prevent the multi checked radio buttons in the same question

Comment: As they should, I meant you also give the same name to the text box and have a js script that you call on 'onsubmit' of the form to sort of validate it by disabling the radio boxes of the questions which users have filled in the text box for.

Comment: that is okay with the radio buttons but i have the ability to add question with check box options and can have the "other" option

Comment: So you want to add a fourth radio button that when clicked will generate a text input that will allow people to add some text?

Comment: okay i will try this                                                   it will take some time thank you